# How do i access the data in json object in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access a the data in a json object using angular but i finding it difficult to this at the moment and hopefully you can help me here.

so i have a function in my controller like this:

```
var vm = this;
vm.getData = getData;
vm.data = [];


 function getData() {
        var promise = appService.getAll(vm.query);
        promise.then(function(response) {
            vm.data = response.data,
                    console.log(vm.data);
            },
            function(error) {
                $log.error("an error here", error);
            });


    }
```

and my view goes something like this:

```
<div> 


<table class="table">
        <tr >
            <th> Department</th>


        </tr >
        <tr ng-repeat="n in vm.data">
            <td>{{n.sectionName}} </td>
        </tr>


    </table>


</div>
```

Everything works .. i retrieve my json object as required .. but its just accessing them is where i am having in issue as the above context in my view is not dispplayed .. 
so in my example above i am trying to acess a json with the heaser of "sectionName" and displaying it in my view.

here is a visual of of the json object in my console ...
[image]

Thank you for your time

Comment: if the response object as in the image have results as the data array, then why you call response.data, shouldn't it be response.results?

Comment: yup .. its exactly that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over the object itself. Instead, you have to loop over the results array inside the object.

```
<div> 


<table class="table">
        <tr >
            <th> Department</th>


        </tr >
        <tr ng-repeat="n in vm.data.results">
            <td>{{n.sectionName}} </td>
        </tr>


    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: yup thats right .. it was vm.data.response.results.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `results` is the data you need to display, then you should adjust your markup to be this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in vm.data.results">
    <td>{{n.sectionName}} </td>
</tr>
```